# How to forward incoming clients based on ip to a specific process

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I have a server that has multiple ip addresses. It also has multiple web apps written in nodejs that I'm running.

In short I'd like to forward specific ip addresses to specific node applications. How is this done? Should I use apache or nginx?

running centos 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any running application can bind to either 0.0.0.0 (to catch all the packets) or to some specific IP (it must use this ip when it calls bind() on the socket). Thus almost any TCP/IP server application has option like "Listen" in it's config file or command line, so you should read your docs carefully to figure out how can it be made in your particular application. For Apache it's port-based virtual hosts.

If you want to route user requests to different application based on user's IP address, you should read about iptables nat table and REDIRECT target.